# Where to store a preview of a UIDocument?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uidocument

I'm working on `UIDocument` application and I'd like to show the user a preview of the document before he opens it. I can render that preview into an image when the document get's closed. But where should I save that image? In an other file? or is there a designated way to do this?

Right now I'm developing it without iCloud support. But I want to have a solution that would work with iCloud too. The `UIDocument` is a `UIManagedDocument`. But saving the image into the database would make it kind a pointless. Because then I have to open the document before I can get the preview.

What do you recommend here? Where to put a preview for a `UIManagedDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save an image under (app_directory)/Library/Caches. That way iCloud won't affect your app.

Comment: But this way. If I move the document into the iCloud. The preview is local on this machine. And it is not synched over the iCloud. That means I have to regenerate the preview on every client. And for that I have to open/close every document once.

Comment: Then you should save it in (app_directory)/Documents. Everything that goes in that folder gets automatically synced with iCloud.

Comment: Well non of the solutions seem to be perfect. But I'll go with the /Library/Caches and then regenerate all the previews on all devices.

Comment: Actually according to wwdc12 materials it is recommended to store preview files in Data directory of you ubiquity container -1

Answer (score 3):

You can store your documents in your ubiquity container's *Documents* directory and document preview files in the container's *Data* directory.

If preview file names will be based on the documents names you will be able to use metadata query result to get the document names and then resolve document preview urls.

This way you could download the document previews only but not the whole document.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about *UIManagedDocuments*, but in case of a *UIDocument* I would recommend using a NSFileWrapper as file format (where the document is actually a bundled folder) and save the preview within the document, as **"Preview.jpg"** (or .png) inside a folder labeled **"QuickLook"**.
This way, you'll get the preview in Finder on the Mac as well (for free).

Of course this may or may not be an ideal solution (also depending on if your document is text-only). But it might be a good hint for working with previews for UIDocuments in general.